set scroll to top using Barba Js
I am new using Barba Js, after turning the page the scroll remains in its previous position, I would like it to reset and return to 0, how can I do? I leave the code:
function pageTransition() {
  var tl = gsap.timeline();

  tl.to(".transition", {
    duration: 1,
    scaleY: 1,
    transformOrigin: "bottom",
    ease: "power4.inOut",
  });

  tl.to(".transition", {
    duration: 1,
    scaleY: 0,
    transformOrigin: "top",
    ease: "power4.inOut",
    delay: 0.2,
  });
}

function contentAnimation() {
  var tl = gsap.timeline();
  tl.to("h1", {
    top: 0,
    duration: 1,
    ease: "power3.inOut",
    delay: 0.75,
  });
}

function delay(n) {
  n = n || 0;
  return new Promise((done) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      done();
    }, n);
  });
}

barba.init({
  sync: true,
  transitions: [
    {
      async leave(data) {
        const done = this.async();

        pageTransition();
        await delay(1000);
        done();
      },

      async enter(data) {
        contentAnimation();
      },

      async once(data) {
        contentAnimation();
      },
    },
  ],
});

This is what I tried but I didn't know how to apply it therefore I couldn't solve it
Barba.Dispatcher.on('newPageReady', function(current, prev, container) { history.scrollRestoration = 'manual'; });
